# Collision Problems with Hair Particles (Hair Dynamics) during animation

Tags: animation, particles, physics, hair, collision

I’m having trouble with a character that has a particle hair system. I want the hair to move realistically, so I enabled hair dynamics in the particle settings. However, the hair particles don’t collide with the character’s head, and they pass through it. I tried adding a collision modifier (under physics properties) to the head mesh, but that made the hair explode and disappear after a few frames. I adjusted the settings for hair dynamics and collision, but nothing worked. I don’t know what I’m doing wrong. Can anyone help me fix this issue?
Thank You in advance!

There’s a ScullCap Object which is acting as the emitter for the hair particles. The emitter is hidden in the viewport display as well as render (The show emitter check box is un-ticked in the Particle System properties).

I’ve attached a google drive link to the video and the file. Here’s the link:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11-4Eja4vaXvj0eeB2bV0hIc_HBE1ZaIn?usp=sharing

Here are some screenshots as well:

[image: The character when the animation isn’t playing.]

[image: Animation is being played and the Head object doesn’t have a collider. The Hair Dynamics are baked here.]

[image: Hair Particle explosion, upon adding the collider to the head mesh and scrubbing through the timeline. The hair dynamics aren’t baked.]

[image: Hair Dynamics are baked and the head mesh has a collider. When I play the animation in this scenario, the hair particles just disappear, after a few frames.]